# The type or namespace name 'ProtoContractAttribute' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I'm trying to test Protobuf-net and am getting the above error when trying to build the project (along with several other errors saying 'ProtoContract', 'ProtoMember', 'ProtoMemberAttribute' could not be found). I've made sure that protobuf-net is installed in the project, and tried all possible Protobuf using statements (Compiler, Meta, and Serializers), but it still does not build. The following is my code:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class TestClass
{
    #region fields
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string name;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public object value;
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public object xFValue;
    #endregion

    public TestClass();
}
```

Also, I am on .NET 4.5.2

Any ideas as to what's going on? Thanks!

edit: as maccettura said below, the problem is that I didn't include the statement "using Protobuf;"

Comment: Did you install via nuget package?  Are you certain it installed properly?  Are you using the required `using` directive: `using ProtoBuf;`?

Comment: Oh, thank you! i didn't add using Protobuf like an idiot. That seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I know this is a newbie question, but how do I close a question if it's answered through a comment?

Comment: I can add an answer and you can mark it

Comment: pro tip: if you press ctrl and period you get a drop down which will offer to add any missing `using` directives (if you are already referencing the dll) - [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFAu6.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely forgot to include the appropriate `using` directive.

According to the docs, `ProtoContract` lives in the "ProtoBuf" namespace so try this:

```
using ProtoBuf;
```

and that should solve your problem.

Comment: You got it right in the comments but have it wrong in your answer. A `using` *statement* allows for an object that implements `IDisposable` to be cleaned up at the appropriate moment. A `using` *directive* is what brings additional names into scope without requiring qualified names to be used.

Comment: I was answering another question at the same time which was related to `IDisposable` haha, thank you for catching my grammar error

Answer (score 2):

As maccetura said in the comments, the problem is that I didn't include the statement "using Protobuf;" Seems to compile now.